# Pause/Resume Video Recording like Instagram

Tags: ios, video-capture, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I try to get some help. I would like to Pause/Resume a video recording on iOS. But it's very complicated. My goal is to get something like in the app of Instagram App (when you press it 's recording).
I find the "CapturePause" app example but it's very complicated from me. A lot of stream bytes algorithm. too complex for me.

I try to develop the solution by using multiple AvCaptureMovieFileOutput, but it's very complicated. And I am losing my mind in it.

Does anyone know a framework or piece of code to do it nicely ? I searched on GG and I found something.

Thank you,

Arnaud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am also finding similar to Instagram recording.. i find pause recoding

https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision

i thing helping something

Comment: Hi, did you find something better? I'm also finding similar thing.

Comment: @SpencerWong yeah  alos got similar please check that https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder